# Is the word "Shinobi" an accepted English word?

Tags: word-choice, translation

I've been wondering if the word "Shinobi" is an accepted English word. As far as I know, its synonym "Ninja" is an accepted English word where "Spy" is the nearest common English.

Comment: I've personally never encountered it. Did you check any English dictionaries?

Comment: It's certainly not *common*. I suspect it may fight against ninja for currency.

Comment: No. Why would I use a rarely known Japanese word, when I had an English word for it already?

Comment: The simple answer is **no**, as of writing.  Japanese words like Katana, Ninja etc are beloved by the English-speaking countries.  The new one you mention could well be used by, say, a motorbike company or something as a model name, or perhaps a film title, and it would become more and more popular, perhaps .. joining old favorites such as "ninja".

Comment: Joe Blow, I haven't heard of the word *Katana*. Where in the English-speaking world is it used and what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the audience. For a general audience, it seems *shinobi* would not be understood.

Wikipedia has a list of English words of Japanese origin, and *shinobi* is not on that list, not that educated native speakers would be expected to know all those words, however.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Japanese_origin

Some native speakers of English who are pretty fluent in Japanese (such as myself) don’t even know the word *shinobi*. Just don’t read much about ninjas, I guess.

However, in the context of ninjas, *shinobi* does seems to be understood. Here is a book title at Amazon that uses the term:

*The Secret Traditions of the Shinobi: Hattori Hanzo's Shinobi Hiden and Other Ninja Scrolls*

Comment: Agreed.  I know I've heard it in videogame contexts, but I don't think I'd expect any English speaker to know it.